# Azure data factory - replace json \r\n

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, regexp-replace

I have an API response which contains \r\n. I am not able to replace it by using `replace(string, '\r\n', '')`. It does not work for it. When I use `replace(string, 'r', '')` it replaced every word which contains <kbd>r</kbd> except <kbd>\r</kbd>. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Are you using pipeline activities and trying to use replace in as set variable? If not, please specify the activities that you are using?

Comment: Yes, I append it to variable

Comment: Can you please provide sample of how the response looks?

Comment: Sql error number: 51000. Error Message: Error!  Tab.table\r\nRun_ID = 405;

Comment: I've done it by using replace(string, decodeUriComponent(%0D%0A'), '')

Comment: You can also change the pipeline json as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/xsmLEbQ.png). It would automatically change the dynamic content. When you debug, it would return [required output](https://i.imgur.com/V4d87Oj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by using replace(string, decodeUriComponent(%0D%0A'), '')

Answer (score 0):

The approach provided by [@inspiredd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13023189/inspiredd) works. The following is the reason why replacing `\r\n` does not work in pipeline expression builder.

- The following is the data that I have which contains the values `\r\n`. I have taken this response from look up for demonstration.

[image]

- When I enter the expression `@replace(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].error,'\r\n','')` in set variable, it won't give expected output because, in the pipeline activity json, the dynamic content will be considered as `\\r\\n` instead.

[image]

- You can simply edit this pipeline JSON to simply use `\r\n` instead of `\\r\\n\`.
- This will change the dynamic content as shown below:

[image]

- Running the code will give the expected result and replace the values. This is an [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q83y8.png) for reference.